# Ant: Iterating through an XML file's nodes

Tags: ant, email-attachments

I have the following XML structure:

```
<servers>
    <hostname>ABC01</hostname>
    <hostname>ABC02</hostname>
</servers>
```

I need to retrieve a file from each server, from a folder I know, attach it to an email and then send it.

What would be the approach for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`xmlproperty` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/xmlproperty.html) to load an XML file into properties.

Then use the [`for` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html) from [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) to act upon each of the matched properties.

Something like:

```
<target name="funtimes">
    <xmlproperty file="the.xml" delimiter=","/>
    <for list="${servers.hostname}" param="hostname">
        <sequential>
            <echo>Doing things with @{hostname}</echo>
        </sequential>
    </for>
</target>
```

Fetching files depends upon how you are planning to access them. The [`scp` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html) might help.

For sending email you can use the [`mail` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/mail.html).

Comment: What I have in mind for fetching the files is copying them one by one to a local shared folder using the for task which you explained me previously.
And then, in the mail task, attaching them to the email putting them all together in a FileSet.
I'm new at Ant and I'm doing some research to see if this is possible :).